# fetch function PDO returns error

Tags: php, pdo

I have the  following definition in PHP PDO that prepare and execute a query. The query is executed but in the end I receive the message: **Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**. I tryed already to use ***FETCH_COLUMN*** but is the same. Can somebody help me?

```
 public function GetIDbyname($name){

            try{

                $stm = $this->pdo
                ->prepare("SELECT id FROM prozess WHERE name = ?");


                $stm->execute(array($name));
                $r = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

                return $r->id;
            } catch (Exception $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Comment: please check var_dump($r)

Comment: Check if `$stm` and `$r` is not null. Error says that you somewhere do `null->someFunctionCall()` instead of `object->someFunctionCall()` Also why use `?` instead of named parameters? `WHERE name = :name`/`->execute(array(':name' => $name))`

Comment: $stm would be null since it's in a function and i do not see it declared as a parameter or anything.

Comment: FETCH_COLUMN returns the value as array hence you should fetch it as $r[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchAll` returns all rows **in a multi-dimensional array**. `$r` is an *array of objects*, not an object itself. The correct way to get your result would be `$r[0]->id`. Or:

If you only want to fetch a single row, use `$stm->fetch()`.

Comment: Hi THX for your answer! But is not working. What you said is absolutly correct, but I don't know where is my problem that is not working. I used fetch() as you also said and nothing

Comment: What does that mean, "nothing"?! Did you try `var_dump($r)` to confirm what you're getting?

Comment: yes, I did I check with var_dump($r) and this is the answer: bool(false) array(2) { ["id"]=> int(85) [0]=> int(85) } Can you pls help me to understand this?

Comment: That either means no matching row was found, or there was an error. `var_dump($stm->errorInfo())`